# Use container width in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

We have recently changed to Bootstrap 4, and I'm looking into all the new ways to set widths, breakpoints etc.

I want to make a div have a `max-width` of the current breakpoint's container width, but I can't find the standard SASS variable name for that specific width.

Note that I can't use classes (e.g. `.col-xl-`) for this, since I don't have access to this specific part of the HTML.

Comment: Are you looking for the sass variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this built-in mixin:

```
// For each breakpoint, define the maximum width of the container in a media query
@mixin make-container-max-widths($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
            width: $container-max-width;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }
}
```

You can create a similar one to your needs like:

```
@mixin make-max-widths-container-width($max-widths: $container-max-widths, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
    @each $breakpoint, $container-max-width in $max-widths {
        @include media-breakpoint-up($breakpoint, $breakpoints) {
            max-width: $container-max-width;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
.my-custom-class{
   @include make-max-widths-container-width();
}
```

"Compiled" CSS produced (with default values on breakpoints and container widths):

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .my-custom-class {
        max-width: 540px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .my-custom-class {
        max-width: 720px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .my-custom-class {
        max-width: 960px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .my-custom-class {
        max-width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted! Nice, I see I have a lot to learn :)

Comment: This looks to be a pretty good solution except that I see that there is no mention of what to do for "extra-small" devices, for which the container width is undefined. This is according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_grid_system.asp). Also, I have used the jQuery `parseInt($('.container').css( 'max-width' ))` and upon printing out the result I get `NaN` when I shrink the window to under 576px. So probably Rvervuurt would have to look into using something like the jQuery `innerWidth` of some element (could be empty) that had been given the `container` class.